# Make footer stick to bottom after metismenu expanding

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery metis menu plugin for my website sidebar, the problem is when second level items of a menu item are more than 5 or 6 the sidebar expands overlapping the footer which postition doesn't change.
I want it to stick to page bottom and not fixed one, any ideas?

Comment: It's a bit unclear, are you wanting the footer to stick to page bottom or the second menu. You want "it" to be stuck to page bottom and not fixed...what do you mean?

Comment: if it's postition is fixed and bottom=0px it will always stick to bottom but appear in scroll-able pages, but i want it at the bottom like any other div

Comment: share your code please